# Ribbon control bug? (causes cutoff in vista)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ribbon

I've found that when I take a simple form containing only a ribbon bar and a status bar, it's cutoff. The control you see above the status bar was later removed. The same cutoff occurs whatever control happens to be present. Later I removed the status bar & put a memo control there instead with the same result.

without ribbon bar:
[image: without ribbon bar]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/OnVista1.png))</sub>

with ribbon bar:
[image: with ribbon bar]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/OnVista2.png))</sub>

i've illustrated this with some drawing 2, 4, and 8 pixels from the edge.

[image: not maximized]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/OnVista3.png))</sub>
[image: maximized]
<sub>(source: [xrw.bc.ca](http://xrw.bc.ca/download/so/OnVista4.png))</sub>

as Chris Lively says below, there's clearly been a miscalculation of the sizes.  how can i correct this?

Thank you for your comments!

Comment: erm... not programming related?
Actually, is this even a question?

Comment: sure it's programming related.  i'm writing a delphi app.

Comment: Luis, how is this not programming related? If you don't know what Delphi is, or that this is about writing a Delphi app, maybe you shouldn't comment on the question.

Comment: It sounds like the standard bug in Delphi of forms not starting positioned properly. First try changing `Position` from `poScreenCenter' to `poDefault`. Then try turning off `AutoSize` (having `AutoSize` on any exposes another Delphi bug, with different caption bar sizes)

Comment: thank you for the info, ian.  it makes no difference.  i wonder if they fixed it in d2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the problem with my previous answer.

There is a workaround to this miscalculation problem I've been able to come up with (quickly).

You can use a custom messagehandler for WM_SYSCOMMAND with the SC_MAXIMIZE wParam parameter. You can then resize your form using the following:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    // other stuff
    procedure WMSyscommand(var Msg: TWMSYSCOMMAND); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;



procedure TForm1.WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSYSCOMMAND);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  // Test for SC_MAXIMIZE. If found...
  if Msg.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE then
  begin
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @R, 0);
    Top := R.Top;
    Left := R.Left;
    Width := R.Right - R.Left;
    Height := R.Bottom - R.Top;
    Msg.Result := 0; // Message handled
  end
  else
    DefaultHandler(Msg);
end;
```

The code above (tested on Vista 32-bit Home Premium with Aero/Glass enabled) works fine.

[image: Image of ribbon left end]

[image: Image of ribbon right end]

[image: Image of status bar]

Comment: nice work, ken!  thank you!  a couple of tiny corrections for whoever may use this later:

  if <b>Msg</b>.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE then
...
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, <b>@R</b>, 0);

Comment: nice work, ken!  thank you!  a couple of tiny corrections for whoever may use this later:  [reposted because HTML not rendered].

  if Msg.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE then
...
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @R, 0);

Comment: Thanks for the correction, X-Ray. I'll fix the typo (I knew I should have copied and pasted instead of retyping. <g>)

Comment: i also discovered that it only works if the form is not set at design time to wsMaximized, this doesn't work.  i can manage but if you know a solution to that as well that'd be wonderful.  i can, of course change to only maximize at runtime.

Comment: Hmmm... Did you try using the code as well (without the message related stuff, of course) in FormCreate or FormShow? FormCreate might be too early... I never use wsMaximized myself; I leave that choice to the user. (You could separate out the API call and size code to a separate method, (more)

Comment: and call that method from both the FormCreate/FormShow and in response to the WM_SysCommand message.

Comment: Just had another thought... Instead of setting wsMaximized, just post your form a WM_SYSCOMMAND message in the FormCreate() event. That would call the existing message handler from my post, which would take care of the problem. PostMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0); should work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Ken White has a few issues:

- Maximize button stays active, can use resize handles on maximised window
- Unable to restore window back to previous size.

So I propose the following:

```
// add to form object
procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(var mmInfo : TWMGETMINMAXINFO); message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;

// implementation
procedure TfrmMain.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var mmInfo: TWMGETMINMAXINFO);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  with mmInfo.MinMaxInfo^ do
  begin
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @R, 0);
    ptMaxPosition.X := R.Left;
    ptMaxPosition.Y := R.Top;
    ptMaxSize.X     := R.Right - R.Left;
    ptMaxSize.Y     :=  R.Bottom - R.Top-1;
  end;
end;
```

Not ideal, as I have to (for some reason) adjust the maxHeight by -1 in order for the default handler to not re-assert itself and move the window to -8,-8,... But it works for me.

Comment: sounds interesting.  thank you; i'll give this a try when i get back to this!